# Alphanumeric email validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regex below to validate email to accept alphanumeric characters. It works in the following cases

1) Must contain atleast one alphabets
2) allow alphanumeric
3) allow special characters `.-and _`

**Regular Expression:**

`/^([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/i`

**Cases:**

`1111@gmail.com - allow`

`aaaa@gmail.com  - allow`

`aa1_aa@gmail.com - allow`

**Output expected:**

`1111@gmail.com - not allow because it does not contain alphabets before @`

`aaaa@gmail.com  - allow`

`a1@gmail.com  - allow`

`1a@gmail.com  - allow`

`aa1_aa@gmail.com - allow`

Hers is jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JCRcQ/97/)

Comment: Where are you getting your rules for email validation?  If you're validating emails from external sources, this isn't a good set of rules to use.  Read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on how to validate or find email addresses.  It provides a really good discussion on some of the trade-offs and imperfections of using regular expressions for this task, as well as providing quite a few excellent regular expressions.

Comment: In our organization we validate using '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$' which is as per standard if you need it

Comment: It’s always tricky to validate e-mail addresses. Something like [this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) tries to support all valid e-mail addresses, and is ridiculous, and will support some obscure things that many e-mail servers won’t take. On the other hand, the popular framework Angular.js uses the following regex, which is more lenient than yours: `/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/` (edit: very similar to the regexp used by @Raunak Kathuria)

Comment: @Nate: Thanks, in that case it accepts `aaa.@gmail.com` its not a valid email

Comment: The best way to validate an e–mail address is to send an e–mail to the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex will do the job, just add this at the beginning

```
(?=[^@]*[A-Za-z])
```

making your final regex like this:

`/^(?=[^@]*[A-Za-z])([a-zA-Z0-9])(([a-zA-Z0-9])*([\._-])?([a-zA-Z0-9]))*@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+(\.))+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/i`

`(?=exp)` is positive look-ahead. It will try to find the expression without taking it into match.  look-ahead actually matches characters, but then gives up the match.

`(?=[^@]*[A-Za-z])` : will match `[^@]*[A-Za-z]`, meaning anything other than `@` followed by a alphabet. So actually it will match if at least one alphabet is present in the part before `@`

You can[refer this for look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var email_to_check = "1111@gmail.com";
email_check=email_to_check.substring(0,email_to_check.lastIndexOf("@"));
var isnum = /^\d+$/.test(email_check);
var email_regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*(){}|:"<>?\/';\\+\-~]*@[a-zA-z]+\.[a-zA-z]+)$/;
email_test = email_regex.test(email_to_check);
if(isnum){
alert("You must enter aleast an Alphabet !")    
}else{
    if(email_test){
           /* code if email is right :) */
        alert("This is corrrect email !")
    }else{

    alert("Enter valid email address !");
    }
   }
```

Remove the special char which you don't want in your checklist.